# MySQL script throwing multiple syntax issues

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, datatable

I am having issues with my SQL script for an assignment for school. I believe there may be some kind of schema or possibly a MySQL syntax error but I do not understand what the errors being displayed are about. I am very new to SQL. Please help me understand what I am doing wrong and guide me in the right direction. My code is to create tables, assign values to the scripts, then lastly output all info in all tables, output two instances of rows, and then to execute two joins with the join keyword using foreign keys. This is my script:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS PiqueExpenses
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE PiqueExpenses

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PiqueExpenses.JobPay
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses.JobPay (
    job_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    pay_rate DOUBLE NULL,
    pay_hrs_worked DOUBLE NULL,
    job_mileage DOUBLE NULL,    
    pay_per_mile DOUBLE NULL,   
  PRIMARY KEY (job_name))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PiqueExpenses.Jobs
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses.Jobs (
    job_id INT NOT NULL,
    job_name VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    job_type VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (job_id)
  INDEX fk_Jobs_JobPay_idx (job_name ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Jobs_JobPay
    FOREIGN KEY (job_name)
    REFERENCES PiqueExpenses.JobPay (job_name)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PiqueExpenses.Employee
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses.Employee (
    emp_id INT NOT NULL,
    job_id INT NULL,
    emp_address VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    emp_city VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    emp_state VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    emp_zip INT NULL,
    emp_phone_num VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (emp_id))
  INDEX fk_Employee_Jobs_idx (emp_id ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Employee_Jobs
    FOREIGN KEY (emp_id)
    REFERENCES PiqueExpenses.Jobs (emp_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PiqueExpenses.EmployeeNames
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses.EmployeeNames (
    emp_fname VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    emp_initial VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    emp_lname VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    emp_id INT NULL,    
  PRIMARY KEY (emp_fname)
  PRIMARY KEY (emp_initial)
  PRIMARY KEY (emp_lname))
  INDEX fk_EmployeeNames_Employee_idx (emp_id ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_EmployeeNames_Employee
    FOREIGN KEY (emp_id)
    REFERENCES PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PiqueExpenses.Customer
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses.Customer (
    cust_id INT NOT NULL,
    emp_id INT NULL,
    cust_address VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    cust_city VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    cust_state VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    cust_zip INT NULL,
    cust_phone_num VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (cust_id))
  INDEX fk_Customer_Employee_idx (cust_phone_num ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Customer_Employee
    FOREIGN KEY (cust_phone_num)
    REFERENCES PiqueExpenses.Employee (cust_phone_num)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PiqueExpenses.CustomerNames
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses.CustomerNames (
    cust_fname VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    cust_initial VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    cust_lname VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    cust_id INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (cust_fname)
  PRIMARY KEY (cust_initial)
  PRIMARY KEY (cust_lname))
  INDEX fk_CustomerNames_Customer_idx (order_tran_id ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_CustomerNames_Customer
    FOREIGN KEY (order_tran_id)
    REFERENCES PiqueExpenses.Customer (order_tran_id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

START TRANSACTION;
USE PiqueExpenses;
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.JobPay (job_name, pay_rate, pay_hrs_worked, 
job_mileage, pay_per_mile) VALUES ('CCTV', 32.00, 4, 48.0, .53);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.JobPay (job_name, pay_rate, pay_hrs_worked, 
job_mileage, pay_per_mile) VALUES ('Network', 29.50, 3.8, 35.0, .44);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.JobPay (job_name, pay_rate, pay_hrs_worked, 
job_mileage, pay_per_mile) VALUES ('Alarm', 38.75, 7.6, 49.0, .48);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.JobPay (job_name, pay_rate, pay_hrs_worked, 
job_mileage, pay_per_mile) VALUES ('DigitalMenuBoard', 42.00, 8.9, 21.0, 
.25);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.JobPay (job_name, pay_rate, pay_hrs_worked, 
job_mileage, pay_per_mile) VALUES ('Telecom', 31.42, 3.5, 64.0, .58);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.JobPay (job_name, pay_rate, pay_hrs_worked, 
job_mileage, pay_per_mile) VALUES ('DigitalMenuBoard', 42.00, 5.6, 82.0, 
.57);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.JobPay (job_name, pay_rate, pay_hrs_worked, 
job_mileage, pay_per_mile) VALUES ('Alarm', 38.75, 6.7, 57.0, .57);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.JobPay (job_name, pay_rate, pay_hrs_worked, 
job_mileage, pay_per_mile) VALUES ('Telecom', 31.42, 4.8, 66.0, .61);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.JobPay (job_name, pay_rate, pay_hrs_worked, 
job_mileage, pay_per_mile) VALUES ('Network', 29.50, 4.4, 52.0, .49);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.JobPay (job_name, pay_rate, pay_hrs_worked, 
job_mileage, pay_per_mile) VALUES ('CCTV', 32.00, 6.4, 70.0, .50);

COMMIT;

START TRANSACTION;
USE PiqueExpenses;
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Jobs (job_id, job_name, job_type) VALUES (0001, 
'CCTV', 'Install');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Jobs (job_id, job_name, job_type) VALUES (0002, 
'Network','Install');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Jobs (job_id, job_name, job_type) VALUES (0003, 
'Alarm', 'Time&Mater');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Jobs (job_id, job_name, job_type) VALUES (0004, 
'DigitalMenuBoard', 'Install');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Jobs (job_id, job_name, job_type) VALUES (0005, 
'Telecom', 'Troubleshoot');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Jobs (job_id, job_name, job_type) VALUES (0004, 
'DigitalMenuBoard', 'Install');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Jobs (job_id, job_name, job_type) VALUES (0003, 
'Alarm', 'Troubleshoot');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Jobs (job_id, job_name, job_type) VALUES (0005, 
'Telecom', 'Troubleshoot');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Jobs (job_id, job_name, job_type) VALUES (0002, 
'Network', 'Troubleshoot');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Jobs (job_id, job_name, job_type) VALUES (0001, 
'CCTV', 'Install');

COMMIT;

START TRANSACTION;
USE PiqueExpenses;
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id, job_id, emp_address, emp_city, 
emp_state, emp_phone_num) VALUES (44201, 0001, '7613 Bellflower', 'Mentor', 
'OH', '44060', '1-(440)654-7744');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id, job_id, emp_address, emp_city, 
emp_state, emp_phone_num) VALUES (44202, 0002, '2346 15th', 'Akron', 'OH', 
'44314', '1-(330)848-9413');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id, job_id, emp_address, emp_city, 
emp_state, emp_phone_num) VALUES (44203, 0003, '6915 Giddings', 'Atwater', 
'OH', '44201', '1-(330)358-2026');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id, job_id, emp_address, emp_city, 
emp_state, emp_phone_num) VALUES (44204, 0004, '11241 Mahoning', 'North 
Jackson', 'OH', '44451', '1-(330)666-9283');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id, job_id, emp_address, emp_city, 
emp_state, emp_phone_num) VALUES (44205, 0005, '685 Deercrest', 'Wadsworth', 
'OH', '44281', '1-(330)954-2209');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id, job_id, emp_address, emp_city, 
emp_state, emp_phone_num) VALUES (44206, 0004, '675 Wolf Ledges', 'Akron', 
'OH', '44309', '1-(330)996-9756');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id, job_id, emp_address, emp_city, 
emp_state, emp_phone_num) VALUES (44207, 0003, '111 Center', 'Medina', 'OH', 
'44256', '1-(330)335-1803');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id, job_id, emp_address, emp_city, 
emp_state, emp_phone_num) VALUES (44208, 0005, '222 State', 'Cuyahoga 
Falls', 'OH', '44223', '1-(330)388-6354');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id, job_id, emp_address, emp_city, 
emp_state, emp_phone_num) VALUES (44209, 0002, '489 Bridge', 'Brimfield', 
'OH', '44240', '1-(330)321-6223');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Employee (emp_id, job_id, emp_address, emp_city, 
emp_state, emp_phone_num) VALUES (44210, 0001, '44 Chitauqua', 'Cleveland', 
'OH', '44134', '1-(678)980-0852');

COMMIT;

START TRANSACTION;
USE PiqueExpenses;
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.EmployeeNames (emp_fname, emp_initial, emp_lname, 
emp_id) VALUES ('Tom', 'I', 'Butler', 44201);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.EmployeeNames (emp_fname, emp_initial, emp_lname, 
emp_id) VALUES ('Marty', 'M', 'Tucker', 44202);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.EmployeeNames (emp_fname, emp_initial, emp_lname, 
emp_id) VALUES ('Tammy', 'T', 'Rivera', 44203);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
S
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.EmployeeNames (emp_fname, emp_initial, emp_lname, 
emp_id) VALUES ('Alicia', 'L', 'Robinson', 44204);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.EmployeeNames (emp_fname, emp_initial, emp_lname, 
emp_id) VALUES ('Mary', 'J', 'Watson', 44205);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.EmployeeNames (emp_fname, emp_initial, emp_lname, 
emp_id) VALUES ('Rachel', 'J', 'Owens', 44206);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.EmployeeNames (emp_fname, emp_initial, emp_lname, 
emp_id) VALUES ('Barb', 'L', 'Wright', 44207);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.EmployeeNames (emp_fname, emp_initial, emp_lname, 
emp_id) VALUES ('Peter', 'F', 'Parker', 44208);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.EmployeeNames (emp_fname, emp_initial, emp_lname, 
emp_id) VALUES ('Kathy', 'W', 'Alvarez', 44209);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.EmployeeNames (emp_fname, emp_initial, emp_lname, 
emp_id) VALUES ('Frank', 'M', 'Morris', 44210);

COMMIT;

START TRANSACTION;
USE PiqueExpenses;
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Customer (cust_id, emp_id, cust_address, 
cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_phone_num) VALUES (22001, 44201, '4123 
Anniversary Road', 'Nashville', 'TN', '37215', '1-(615)995-7744');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Customer (cust_id, emp_id, cust_address, 
cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_phone_num) VALUES (22002, 44202, '9807 
Ruskin Crossing', 'Bellevue', 'WA', '98008', '1-(425)975-9413');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Customer (cust_id, emp_id, cust_address, 
cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_phone_num) VALUES (22003, 44203, '39 
Montana Parkway', 'Saint Paul', 'MN', '55166', '1-(651)866-2047');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Customer (cust_id, emp_id, cust_address, 
cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_phone_num) VALUES (22004, 44204, '3 
Westridge Street', 'Stamford', 'CT', '06905', '1-(203)677-2492');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Customer (cust_id, emp_id, cust_address, 
cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_phone_num) VALUES (22005, 44205, '659 
Homewood Junction', 'Gary', 'IN', '46406', '1-(219)971-2522');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Customer (cust_id, emp_id, cust_address, 
cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_phone_num) VALUES (22006, 44206, 
'86460 Kensington Place', 'Columbus', 'OH', '43240', '1-(614)282-8239');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Customer (cust_id, emp_id, cust_address, 
cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_phone_num) VALUES (22007, 44207, '4360 
Bluestem Pass', 'Bradenton', 'FL', '34205', '1-(941)335-5180');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Customer (cust_id, emp_id, cust_address, 
cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_phone_num) VALUES (22008, 44208, '0178 
Hallows Pass', 'San Antonio', 'TX', '78265', '1-(210)523-6354');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Customer (cust_id, emp_id, cust_address, 
cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_phone_num) VALUES (22009, 44209, '1816 
Trailsway Alley', 'Sacramento', 'CA', '94245', '1-(916)618-3467');
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.Customer (cust_id, emp_id, cust_address, 
cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_phone_num) VALUES (22010, 44210, 
'72464 Armistice Drive', 'San Jose', 'CA', '95133', '1-(408)405-1270');

COMMIT;

START TRANSACTION;
USE PiqueExpenses;
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.CustomerNames (cust_fname, cust_initial, 
cust_lname, cust_id) VALUES ('Fred', 'F', 'Flinstone', 22001);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.CustomerNames (cust_fname, cust_initial, 
cust_lname, cust_id) VALUES ('Buford', 'L', 'Tannen', 22002);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.CustomerNames (cust_fname, cust_initial, 
cust_lname, cust_id) VALUES ('Yosimite', 'P', 'Sam', 22003);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.CustomerNames (cust_fname, cust_initial, 
cust_lname, cust_id) VALUES ('John', 'A', 'Wayne', 22004);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.CustomerNames (cust_fname, cust_initial, 
cust_lname, cust_id) VALUES ('James', 'K', 'Hetfield', 22005);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.CustomerNames (cust_fname, cust_initial, 
cust_lname, cust_id) VALUES ('Lars', 'P', 'Ulrich', 22006);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.CustomerNames (cust_fname, cust_initial, 
cust_lname, cust_id) VALUES ('Kirk', 'Q', 'Hammet', 22007);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.CustomerNames (cust_fname, cust_initial, 
cust_lname, cust_id) VALUES ('Robert', 'F', 'Trajillo', 22008);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.CustomerNames (cust_fname, cust_initial, 
cust_lname, cust_id) VALUES ('Alfred', 'P', 'Yankovich', 22009);
INSERT INTO PiqueExpenses.CustomerNames (cust_fname, cust_initial, 
cust_lname, cust_id) VALUES ('Odell', 'X', 'Beckham', 22010);

COMMIT;

START TRANSACTION;
USE PiqueExpenses;

SELECT  * 
FROM    JobPay, 
        Jobs, 
        EmployeeNames, 
        Employee, 
        CustomerNames, 
        Customer;

SELECT  * 
FROM    JobPay 
WHERE   job_name = 'Alarm';

SELECT  * 
FROM    Jobs 
WHERE   job_type = 'Install';

SELECT *
FROM Jobs
LEFT OUTER JOIN JobPay ON Jobs.job_name = JobPay.job_name

UNION

SELECT *
FROM Jobs
RIGHT OUTER JOIN JobPay ON Jobs.job_name = JobPay.job_name;

SELECT *
FROM Customer
LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomerNames ON Customer.cust_id = CustomerNames.cust_id

UNION

SELECT *
FROM Customer
RIGHT OUTER JOIN CustomerNames ON Customer.cust_id = CustomerNames.cust_id;
```

Here are errors:
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8' at line 2

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PiqueExpenses.JobPay CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpens' at line 3

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses.Jobs (  job_id INT NOT NULL,  job_name ' at line 2

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses.Employee (  emp_id INT NOT NULL,  job_i' at line 2

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses.EmployeeNames (  emp_fname VARCHAR(45) ' at line 2

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses.Customer (  cust_id INT NOT NULL,  emp_' at line 2

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses.CustomerNames (  cust_fname VARCHAR(45)' at line 2

1 warning(s): 3135 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.

Error Code: 1049. Unknown database 'piqueexpenses'

Error Code: 1146. Table 'piqueexpenses.jobpay' doesn't exist

Error Code: 1049. Unknown database 'piqueexpenses'

Error Code: 1146. Table 'piqueexpenses.jobs' doesn't exist

Error Code: 1146. Table 'piqueexpenses.employee' doesn't exist

Error Code: 1146. Table 'piqueexpenses.employeenames' doesn't exist

Error Code: 1146. Table 'piqueexpenses.customer' doesn't exist

Error Code: 1146. Table 'piqueexpenses.customernames' doesn't exist

Error Code: 1046. No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS list in the sidebar.

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8' at line 2

0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 3135 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.

Error Code: 1146. Table 'piqueexpenses.jobpay' doesn't exist

Error Code: 1146. Table 'piqueexpenses.jobs' doesn't exist

Error Code: 1146. Table 'piqueexpenses.employee' doesn't exist

Error Code: 1146. Table 'piqueexpenses.employeenames' doesn't exist

Error Code: 1146. Table 'piqueexpenses.customer' doesn't exist

Error Code: 1146. Table 'piqueexpenses.customernames' doesn't exist

Error Code: 1046. No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS list in the sidebar.

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8' at line 2

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PiqueExpenses.JobPay CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpens' at line 3

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses.Jobs (  job_id INT NOT NULL,  job_name ' at line 2

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses.Employee (  emp_id INT NOT NULL,  job_i' at line 2

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses.EmployeeNames (  emp_fname VARCHAR(45) ' at line 2

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses.Customer (  cust_id INT NOT NULL,  emp_' at line 2

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PiqueExpenses.CustomerNames (  cust_fname VARCHAR(45)' at line 2

0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 3135 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.

Comment: `but I do not understand what the errors being displayed are about.` - it would be helpful if you actually included the errors in your question...

Comment: I agree that we need the actual error message(s), but I have to ask: what's that "S" doing in the middle of the inserts into PiqueExpenses.EmployeeNames ?

Comment: I fixed the 'S' thank you. It was to the far right. I am including edited the initial post to include the output.

Comment: Read & act on [mcve]. In particular, remove code until it is *minimal* to cause an error--for code & input & expected output that you give. Also read [ask] and the [help] the google hits for 'stackexchange homework'. Also tell us what googling your error messages sans table/column names tells you. And google variants on 'more info mysql error'. You really haven't shown any 'research effort'--see the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Answer (score 0):

You have not terminated each **DROP** line with a semi-colon

```
    #MySQL 5.7.12

    SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
    SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
    SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS JobPay;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS JobPay (
        job_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
        pay_rate DOUBLE NULL,
        pay_hrs_worked DOUBLE NULL,
        job_mileage DOUBLE NULL,    
        pay_per_mile DOUBLE NULL,   
      PRIMARY KEY (job_name))
    ENGINE = InnoDB;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Jobs;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Jobs (
        job_id INT NOT NULL,
        job_name VARCHAR(45) NULL,
        job_type VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (job_id)
      INDEX fk_Jobs_JobPay_idx (job_name ASC),
      CONSTRAINT fk_Jobs_JobPay
        FOREIGN KEY (job_name)
        REFERENCES PiqueExpenses.JobPay (job_name)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

When confronted with many errors, cut-down the extent of the problem until you detect just the first error. Deal with that error, then add a bit more of your code until you find the next error. Deal with that error, then add a bit more of your code until you find the next error. repeat until done.

i.e. treat your code like a salami, cut it into bit size slices

I did not attempt to test every part of your code, but it's pretty clear those lines referring to DROP need help first.